# QT5 Eclipse weird syntax error

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, qt5

I'm using Eclipse 4.5 for implementation some GUIs with QT5. CMAKE is used to compile my projects. So, Eclipse shows me some errors like invalid arguments

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<#0>::Object *, #0, const QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<#1>::Object *, #1, enum Qt::ConnectionType)
QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *, const char *, const QObject *, const char *, enum Qt::ConnectionType)
QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *, const QMetaMethod &, const QObject *, const QMetaMethod &, enum Qt::ConnectionType)
QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *, const char *, const char *, enum Qt::ConnectionType)
QtPrivate::QEnableIf<1 11 14 129 1 74 0 ArgumentCount 14 QtPrivate::FunctionPointer 1 #1 103 4225 0 74 01 11 14 129 1 74 0 ArgumentCount 14 QtPrivate::FunctionPointer 1 #1 103 4225 0 74 0,QMetaObject::Connection>::Type connect(const QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<#0>::Object *, #0, #1)
QtPrivate::QEnableIf<1 15 1 11 14 129 1 74 0 ArgumentCount 14 QtPrivate::FunctionPointer 1 #1 103 4225 0 74 0 15 7 74 0 IsPointerToMemberFunction 14 QtPrivate::FunctionPointer 1 #1 01 15 1 11 14 129 1 74 0 ArgumentCount 14 QtPrivate::FunctionPointer 1 #1 103 4225 0 74 0 15 7 74 0 IsPointerToMemberFunction 14 QtPrivate::FunctionPointer 1 #1 0,QMetaObject::Connection>::Type connect(const QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<#0>::Object *, #0, const QObject *, #1, enum Qt::ConnectionType)
QtPrivate::QEnableIf<1 28 74 0 ArgumentCount 14 QtPrivate::FunctionPointer 1 #1 15 3 103 4225 1 74 1 01 28 74 0 ArgumentCount 14 QtPrivate::FunctionPointer 1 #1 15 3 103 4225 1 74 1 0,QMetaObject::Connection>::Type connect(const QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<#0>::Object *, #0, #1)
QtPrivate::QEnableIf<1 28 74 0 ArgumentCount 14 QtPrivate::FunctionPointer 1 #1 15 3 103 4225 1 74 1 01 28 74 0 ArgumentCount 14 QtPrivate::FunctionPointer 1 #1 15 3 103 4225 1 74 1 0,QMetaObject::Connection>::Type connect(const QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<#0>::Object *, #0, const QObject *, #1, enum Qt::ConnectionType)
'   gui.cpp /PROJECT/src    line 161    Semantic Error
```

The funniest thing is that my project compiles without any errors or warnings!

The troublepoint is the funktion QObject:: connect

```
QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(request);
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &MyAPP::onRequestFinished);
```

What is wrong with this function?

Comment: The compilation error has nothing to do with Eclipse. Check if pointer 'this' really points to the instance of class MyApp where you have slot onRequestFinished.

Comment: **this** points to the correct instance and the App works correctly too, but this error highlighting in eclipse is sooo annoying :(

Comment: On Linux? Use Qt Creator.

Comment: Is the Qt integration package installed in eclipse? It must be installed and the project must be created as "Qt Makefile project" (then you can delete the *.pro file and makefile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I do Linux + eclipse + Qt + CMake.

### Qt

- Get latest eclipse and then install the Qt package in it through "Help -> Install New Software".
- Create an empty "workspace" directory outside the CMake project source directory.
- Launch eclipse and switch to that "workspace" directory.
- Create a C++ -> Makefile Project -> Qt Makefile Project.
- Delete *.pro file, makefile and main.cpp from it.

### Sources

- Go to Project Properties -> Paths and Symbols -> Source Location -> Link Folder.
- Check "Advanced" and link the source folder of CMake project like that: `../../myproject/`. It works because the workspace is just outside the CMake project directory.

### CMake generator

- Create `Release` folder in the project.
- Go to "Make Target" view (Ctrl+3 and then type "Make Target" if it's hard to find). "Make Target" view looks just like the project view.
- Right click on the "Release" folder and "New...".
- Uncheck "Same as target name", uncheck "Use builder settings".
- Type in "Release" into "Target name" field, leave "Make target" empty, "Build command" is something like "cmake ../../../myproject/". Click ok.
- Double click on this "Release" make target that was just created in the Release folder. It should run cmake.

### Build

- Go to Project Properties, create "Release" configuration.
- Make "Release" configuration active.
- For "Release" configuration uncheck "Generate Makefiles automatically".
- Set Build directory to "Release".
- Enable parallel build.

It should build now in "Release" directory. If it doesn't, remove all from the "Release" directory and rerun cmake by double-clicking on "Release" target in the "Make Target" view as before.

Comment: A really good tutorial, but that doesn't solve my problem. I'm using eclipse like a text editor with an autocompletition-function only. The switchig to the old connect-syntax (connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onRequestFinished()))) helps, but it still not the solution.

Comment: This is strange, because I've got no problems with that highlighting. Maybe it's a C++11 problem? Try adding `-std=c++11` to "Window" -> "Preferences" -> "C/C++" -> "Build" -> "Settings" -> "Discovery" -> "CDT GCC Built-In Compiler Settings". Check how it parses C++11.